# Procedimiento almacenado en MySQL sólo entra en else

Tags: mysql, stored-procedure, depuración

Tengo un procedimiento almacenado, que indica la letra introducida se corresponde realmente con la letra introducida. Si es correcto devuelve 1, y falla, devuelve 0.

El problema es que siempre devuelve 0 aunque sea un DNI válido. Mi código es el siguiente:

```
use iesalandalus2;
DELIMITER //
create function validadni(dni int, letra varchar(1))
    returns tinyint(1)
BEGIN
    declare valor tinyint;
    declare result tinyint;
    declare testigo tinyint;
    if (dni between 0 and 99999999) -- Comprobamos que el numero es válido
        then
        begin
            case letra -- comprbamos que la letra es válida
                when letra = 'T' then set valor = 0;
                when letra = 'R' then set valor = 1;
                when letra = 'W' then set valor = 2;
                when letra = 'A' then set valor = 3;
                when letra = 'G' then set valor = 4;
                when letra = 'M' then set valor = 5;
                when letra = 'Y' then set valor = 6;
                when letra = 'F' then set valor = 7;
                when letra = 'P' then set valor = 8;
                when letra = 'D' then set valor = 9;
                when letra = 'X' then set valor = 10;
                when letra = 'B' then set valor = 11;
                when letra = 'N' then set valor = 12;
                when letra = 'J' then set valor = 13;
                when letra = 'Z' then set valor = 14;
                when letra = 'S' then set valor = 15;
                when letra = 'Q' then set valor = 16;
                when letra = 'V' then set valor = 17;
                when letra = 'H' then set valor = 18;
                when letra = 'L' then set valor = 19;
                when letra = 'C' then set valor = 20;
                when letra = 'K' then set valor = 21;
                when letra = 'E' then set valor = 22;

            end case;
        end;
        begin
            set result = dni % 23; -- Comparamos para saber la letra
            if (result = valor)
                then
                    begin
                        set testigo = 1;
                    end;
                else
                    set testigo = 0;
            end if;
        end;

    end if;
    return testigo;
END; //
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mysql soporta dos tipos de `case`. El que usas, es menos flexible. Básicamente `letra = 'X'` se ejecuta antes de entrar al `case` y el valor de la variable `valor` no se llegaba a asignar.

Lo que deberías hacer es usar el otro tipo de `case` en el que no especificas una variable.

En resumen:

Cambia `case letra`

Por `case`

Te dejo [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3082996).(En inglés) Está mejor explicado.